# Spring Boot: Sort by ManyToOne realtion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's image the following models:

```java
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Book> books;

    <constructor, getters, setters etc.>
}
```

and

```java
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

    <constructor, getters, setters etc.>
}
```

For each model there is a simple PagingAndSortingRepository in use.

Now I like to get all books sorted by the authors name. So my expected request would be something like that: `\books?page=0&size=10&sort=author.name,asc`

This is not working with the default PagingAndSortingRepository, it's no problem to use the `title` as sort param. How could I support the `@ManyToOne` field?

Comment: Can you post your repository and controller, service code.

Comment: I don't use the service and controller. Repository is just that `public interface BookRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Book, Long> {}` same for author

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 as I hear from your comment it will be necessary to implement service and controller

Comment: Yeah it is the standard.